# $scope.gridOptions.api.SelectIndex doesn't work with datasource

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using the server side pagination and filtering example with angularjs.
On loading the data in grid, I would like to programmatically set the first row.
However below method does not work if the grid data has been set using data source.

`$scope.gridOptions.api.selectIndex`

doesn't work with datasource.
It only works after using the $scope.gridOptions.api.setDataSource

I've also opened an issue in github. Below is the link:
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/601

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be expected.

The datasource is the object that will provide your server's data.
As long the datasource is not loaded and did not load the 1st datas you can't use selectIndex method since there is nothing to select.

As a workaround i add myself a custom option in gridOptions where you can provide what you want to select at the 1st loading and select them once my data are loaded the 1st time in my datasource.  I add another callback to be able to compare datas and another when the data is not found.

If you want something simplier you can pass to your datasource a promise that will be resolved once the 1st data get loaded (resolve it after call params.successCallback(data) !)

Note : the callback params.successCallback(data) to send the new data to the grid from the datasource must be called before using selectIndex whatever the solution you use.